# In the circuit of Fig. 3.49, current i1 is: (a) 4 A (b) 3 A (c) 2 A (d) 1 A

Tags: circuit-analysis, analysis, nodal-analysis

[image: figure]

I am starting this subject i need help for this question. If anyone could solve it please tell me.
I don't understand what to do with the nodal analysis. I am thinking to add the 2ohm and 3 ohm resistor in series but I don't know if it is valid or not.
If I add them in series I get answer but can I add them in series even if a battery is in between them.

Comment: This looks like a classic setup for a Thevenin/Norton equivalent source. Are you familiar with these concepts?

Comment: nithya, Yes, you are right about the series 2 and 3 Ohm resistors. They can be re-arranged and then combined. It's harmless to move those 2-terminal series devices around. You can also combine the 1 and 4 Ohm resistors into a single resistor, too.

Comment: @TimWilliams no I don't know them still

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three unknown values in the circuit: v, i1 and i2. To solve this, you need to formulate three equations. The two loops would give two equations. Apply KVL in each of these loops to get the two equations. Isn't the 2A current source in the middle equal to (i2 - i1)? There you go. You now have three equations with three unknowns. Solve this to get the values for i1, i2 and v.

Answer (score 1):

By finding the voltage across the current source you can determine the currents *i*1 & *i*2.

Look up "superposition theorem". It basically states that the voltage at a node of interest is the sum of voltages at the node of interest for each of the sources taken independently. When eliminating sources (turning off), a voltage source becomes a short, a current source becomes an open. The values are such that solving this is easy enough to do the arithmetic in your head, however, please show your work.

By visualizing how the current flows you can simplify the circuit. You can combine the 2 & 3 ohm resistors in to one resistor (*i*1 flows equally through the 2 & 3 ohm resistors), the 1 & 4 ohm resistors can be combined in to one resistor (*i*2 flows equally through the 1 & 4 ohm resistors).

Comment: Thanks for your answer but superposition theorem not started for us